Is it incorrect terminology to say "confidence interval of a random variable"?
I have seen claims that "population paramter is not a random variable" when discussing confidence intervals.
eg here

Be sure to note that the population parameter is not a random variable.

I have no problems accepting that claim in the context of frequentist interpretation. Under that interpretation population parameters are fixed, yet unknown. They are not random variables.
But does the term confidence interval also carry with it that specific interpretation? Or is it simply the mathematical function (as seen on wiki):



For example lets say I consider  (the population parameter) to be a random variable, and X to be random samples. Given their joint distribution, I compute the function:
P( u(x) <  < v(x)) = c     ∀  
which would look something like the red line in the figure below:

(figure borrowed from here)
Now, would I be incorrect in calling the red lines as the "confidence interval of the random variable" ?
Edit: This question is mainly about semantics and received two highly informative answers, for and against the particular usage of given terminology. I have upvoted both (and would have accepted both if that were possible), but I choose not to accept either one because to do so would (IMO) make a judgement on one being more correct than another. In the end the side you pick is subjective (I didn't know this at the time of posting the question), and I leave it upto the future readers to decide for themselves.

By definition, confidence intervals are associated with numerical properties of the distributions of random variables.  Please see our threads about confidence intervals.  Thus, if you hope your audience will understand a phrase like "confidence interval of the random variable," you will need to explain that you are using "confidence interval" in an unconventional manner and you will need to define what you mean by it.

Consult any of the standard texts on statistics or estimation: Kendall, Stuart & Ord; Lehmann; Casella & Berger; etc.  Some of our posts about the definition of CIs provide references.

A common definition of an $(1-\alpha\%)$-confidence interval is that it is a function of the observation $X$ that creates boundaries that will contain the true parameter $\theta$ with a frequency $(1-\alpha\%)$ if we consider the limit of an infinite repetitions of the experiment (and more specifically this frequency of success is independent from a prior for $\theta$).
For this definition it is not neccesary that $\theta$ is a constant and the same each experiment. That underlying nature of the parameter $\theta$ is not important for a confidence interval to be a confidence interval.
For example, it can be that a factory tests the sugar level $\theta$ of a batch of tomato paste, and that sugar level is not constant each batch. Still, you can devise a confidence interval for each batch.
There is however a subtle note about 'the parameter is constant' and that is a topic in the question Are “Data are fixed” in Bayesian viewpoint and “Data are random” in frequentist viewpoint talking about the same thing mathematically? In that discussion I believe that the following quote is the key point:

It is not like the data or parameters are neccesarily considered to be truly fixed, but it is just that the intervals relate to computations of conditional distributions where the one (data/parameter) is computed conditional on the other (parameter/data) being fixed.

It is in the computations, like computations of conditional probabilities, that we consider a parameter to be fixed. But those parameters don't need to be themselves to be fixed.
The expression of coverage probability of a confidence interval is conditional on the parameter value, but it is not neccesarily that the parameter needs to be a constant parameter, it can be a variable as well. That is not to say that the confidence interval of a parameter is considered from a random distribution for the parameter in the same way as in a Bayesian approach where prior and posterior distributions for a parameter are expressed.

It is also a bit a semantical discussion. In the example, the sugar content of a particular batch of tomato paste is both a variable and a definite constant value.

It is a variable from the perspective that batches will have slightly varying unknown sugar content due to all sorts of random factors like tomato variety, sunlight, paste concentration, heat treatment, etc. Each batch will be different.

It is a constant from the perspective that, once the tomato past has been created (and all the random variables have been 'drawn'), it has a fixed true value.


It can be seen as the difference between a variable written as uppercase $Z$ or as lowercase $z$. A confidence interval regards parameters as fixed realisations and not as a variable with a distribution. There is no computation for the probability distribution of the parameter. This is also like the fiducial distribution, related to confidence, is not the same as a probability distribution.

Whether something is a random variable or not is a mathematical issue and not an issue of reality. You can have a probability model in which the sugar level is random, and you can have a probability model in which the sugar level is fixed. Nothing in reality makes the second one wrong and the first one right. All formal definitions of confidence intervals I have seen treat $\theta$ as fixed, and for good reason, because otherwise they'd invite probability statements about $\theta$ given the data, which are not granted.

@ChristianHennig the original thought behind confidence intervals, which is fiducial probability, does treat the interval as a probability statement about $\theta$. It is just that it isn't a probability statement, 'given the data'.

The Wikipedia entry on the history of confidence intervals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#History says otherwise.

@ChristianHennig that Wikipedia entry only tells that the origin is based on two independent thoughts. It doesn't state that the confidence interval is not to be interpreted as a probability statement.

Neyman has stressed on numerous occasions that the parameter in a confidence interval is not random. He may not have been the first to ever compute one, but I'm curious whether you have any reference that backs up the claim that "fiducial probability is the original thought behind confidence intervals". I'd be very surprised.

@ChristianHennig I always thought that it followed from Fisher's inverse probability, like when Clopper and Pearson wrote their article on the confidence/fiducial interval for a binomial proportion. I will have to read on the history alof Neyman's approach to it. Stressing that the parameter is not random might be to stress that the expression of coverage probability is conditional on the parameter value, but that is not neccesarily that the parameter needa to be constant. It can have been a way of speaking to say that the parameter is constant, it is also to differentiate from Bayes.

@ChristianHennig I have still some reading to do (currently working on chapter 5 from "Lectures and Conferences on Mathematical Statistics and Probability") but it is almost pleasantly amusing to read how Neyman and Fisher have been quarreling and disagreeing. To me both their approaches seems very similar in the idea that they consider the distribution of the data given the parameter. Fisher is only more restrictive with the fiducial distribution, which can not always be defined, whereas the idea behind confidence interval can be applied more broadly.

The problem, in my view is that "saying" something is communication, and communication isn't good if it strongly invites misunderstanding.
The notion of confidence interval is associated with the frequentist interpretation of probability, in which the parameter is not a random variable, as you correctly state (at least not in the standard frequentist definition and interpretation of confidence intervals - frequentists can in principle have models that involve a parameter that is a random variable, but then confidence intervals will not treat it as such).
What you can do indeed is to define a setup in which the parameter is a random variable and then compute a confidence interval. Nobody stops you from doing that.
Now you ask whether you can say then that this would be a confidence interval for the random variable $\theta$. I see your point there, but if you say this without giving further explanation, it looks wrong because it ignores that this is not the kind of setup a confidence interval was defined for. Bayesians are usually against confidence intervals, and frequentists are against treating the parameter as random variable. So it would be miscommunication in the sense that both may think you're using the concept wrongly.
And yet technically you have a point. I think if you'd acknowledge the issue, it would work better, like "I'm interested in the behaviour of the confidence interval in a situation in which the $\theta$ is in fact a random variable, generated by some prior. I call this "confidence interval of a random variable", acknowledging that the confidence interval is used here in a situation that is different from the one for which CIs are meant and originally defined."
In fact there can be interest in such experiments, as even from a frequentist point of view there can be processes that give rise to parameters in certain situations that could be described by a prior distribution ("empirical Bayes"), and one could be interested in investigating the characteristics of frequentist procedures such as confidence intervals (that ignore the prior) in such situations.
However also note that in this case the probability statement defining the confidence interval still regards $u(X)$ and $v(X)$ and is conditional on $\theta$, i.e., it is not a probability statement about $\theta$ given the data. This isn't a way to justify Fisher's fiducial probabilities (if you know what that is), trying to make probability statements about $\theta$ out of confidence intervals (I'm presenting this in a "Neymannian" way as a blunder here, well knowing that this has been defended by some very intelligent people, though not on the basis of the argument in question here).

"Now you ask whether you can say then that this would be a confidence interval for the random variable ". This is exactly my question. I now understand why it invites misunderstanding. I still wonder if it's possible conclude precisely about the correctness or incorrectness of the statement? It is entirely possible that semantics isn't that black and white, and we can't definitely call it either correct or incorrect. What do you think?

"the frequentist interpretation of probability, in which the parameter is not a random variable" The frequentist interpretation of probability can just as well consider parameters that are random variables (e.g. parameters that are draws from another distribution, and that distribution has fixed parameters).

@SextusEmpiricus Yeah, arguably later parts of my answer even make that very same point. I'll reword.

@ChristianHennig I was a bit too trigger-happy with accepting this answer. After reading Sextus's answer I'm once again confused. I will think about it some more.

@Shreyans "I still wonder if it's possible conclude precisely about the correctness or incorrectness of the statement?" As a trained mathematician turned statistician I know that many concepts are not defined in the literature in a unique manner, so if you want to be understood you can define your use of wording explicitly and then you should be fine.

@Shreyans Regarding general use of the term CI chances are indeed most would think that this implies the parameter to be fixed (most often found in the literature when defined explicitly), but as you see here, agreement on this is not 100%. Generally there is no absolute authority regarding ultimate correctness of a definition. In some cases there is general agreement, but a term such as CI is used in such a wide range of fields and cultures that you may find disagreement even though the majority of uses implies that there should be a unique definition.


Be sure to note that population parameter is not a random variable.

And then you contradict yourself:

I consider  (the population parameter) to be a random variable.

You can't consider the population parameter to be a random variable. You can:

Get an estimate of a population parameter using a sample
Attempt to determine the theoretical sampling distribution of the sample statistic (could be Normal, t, F, chi-squared, etc)
Generate a confidence interval for the true population parameter by using the sampling distribution of the sample statistic.

At no stage was the population parameter the random variable.  Rather your red lines are the confidence interval of the population paramter (fixed, but unknown) generated using the (random variable) sample statistic.
Further Comment
The distinction between the theoretical, frequentist and Bayesian approaches to probability is deep, but also very subtle. When thinking of probability in the usual sense, we often bypass the thought process of "which paradigm am I approaching this from"?
In general, your issue is not with the concept but that you want to use terminology associated with frequentist interpretations to Bayesian analysis. This will likely confuse others. It could lead them to call you wrong too.
A simple solution is to use Bayesian terminology.
Further Comment 2
A simple way to understand that a clash of philosophies is not easy,and must be managed carefully is the (true) story of someone I knew who was asked in an interview:

What is the probability that a coin toss lands on heads?
The immediate, confident answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ was followed by the brutal
What is the probability that the ceiling of this room will fall today?

And the underlying issue was that the interviewer was considering Bayesian probability (true knowledge of the coin is not known), whereas the interviewee was (rather naively) considering theoretical probability with a fair coin.

"Your statements are contradictory."
No they are not, because the first one is not my statement, it is a quote.

"In general, you can't consider the population parameter to be a random variable". I definitely can, otherwise its impossible to do any kind of bayesian analysis.

So then your statement contradicts the quote. The quote is correct.

"At no stage was the population parameter the random variable". It clearly was, because I defined it to be a RV with given probability distribution.

You are mixing Bayesian and frequentist analysis. Also, the wikipedia page for Bayesian analysis talks about probabilities, not random variables. If you don't know a person's age, you will usually talk about the probability of his age being something, not that his age is a random variable. The issue is more to do with semantics, then concept.

"So then your statement contradicts the quote. The quote is correct." Yes the quote is correct, but it doesn't mean my statement is incorrect. The quote is using a frequentist viewpoint, where the parameter is fixed and samples are random. But I can definitely choose a Bayesian viewpoint and model the parameter as a random variable with some prior distribution. What am i missing?

When using a Bayesian approach use Bayesian wording sich as credible interval as well. When I read 'confidence intervall' I think Frequentism.

@Starlight I apologise for messing up the order of the comment replies, I'm a slow typer/thinker. I do appreciate your much quicker responses. And you are correct, my issue is entirely to do with semantics.

@Starlight "Also, the wikipedia page for Bayesian analysis talks about probabilities, not random variables. If you don't know a person's age, you will usually talk about the probability of his age being something, not that his age is a random variable." Going with your example, lets say there is a room with person A of age 20 and person B of age 30. I will select a person at random. I can call this selected person's age a random variable. In the end a random variable is simply a function that maps every outcome to a value. Here we map A to 20 and B to 30.

@Bernhard "When I read 'confidence intervall' I think Frequentism." Thats exactly my question. There is a mathematical definition of confidence interval, and the math does not care about the interpretation. What if I start with a Bayesian RV and apply the mathematical equation for "confidence interval"? Is it semantically correct to say then that I have calculated confidence interval of a RV?

You need to define a Bayesian RV first.

@Starlight There isn't a 'Bayesian' RV. It is Bayesian to consider the population parameter a RV. I would correct the comment but I don't think i can edit it.

Do you have a reference which says the population parameter is an RV? It would be good to look at that.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83751/77234
Try this link for example.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think your confusion stems from the fact that we usually have expressions such as $P(a<X<b)$ where $X$, the random variable, sits in the middle so we read it as the probability of $X$ falling in the interval $[a,b]$.
Now, how do we read the expression you give for the probability of the CI containing the parameter? What's random in it? And why not the parameter which in your notation 'takes the place' of the RV?
Thing is, the randomness comes from the interval itself, the 95% interval for the sample mean of a bunch of iid normal RV is given by
$$
\bar{X} \pm 1.96 \sigma/\sqrt{n}
$$.
Here the sample mean is a random variable, representing all possible sample means that we could obtain by sampling n observations, adding them up and dividing them by n. Its distribution is called the sampling distribution.
So, the interval itself it's random, you can imagine that every time you get a sample and compute the CI its bounds will fall somewhere on the number line. Sometimes they'll fall around $\theta$ and other times it wasn't. How often that happens is precisely
$P(l(X) <\theta<u(X))=1-\alpha$ and notice that $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is a random vector.
